# Unable to connect index.html in public folder with index.js in src folder

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase-hosting

I'm new to react.j and am still learning. I made a test website and want to host it on firebase. When I deployed my app, only my index.html folder was rendered (the background shows since it is declared in the index.html), but none of my javascript files in the src was rendered. My website runs file locally but isn't working on deployment.

[Here is my public folder with my index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOVlQ.png)

[Here is my src folder with my index.js and other js files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH4Ov.png)

Here is my index.html code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body
    style="
        text-align: center;
        background-image: url('https://www.treehugger.com/thmb/7KYmuAKvOj3cDpRK47BMO8rwUDU=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/__opt__aboutcom__coeus__resources__content_migration__treehugger__images__2019__08__clouds-2dcb0f4cf2934a48bd173b6474c4784c.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    "
>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Here is my index.js code

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
// import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
<div className="Outer">
    <App />
</div>,
document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

[Here is my build tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW25S.png)

The index.html in my build is identical to the one in my public folder shown above.

This is the website right now: https://weatherman-9860a.web.app/

I think I'm missing out on a step since I am just learning. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You attached identical screenshots

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated it.

Comment: I don't know about your environment and how you're deploying your project. But what you see in build/dist directory? Usually you build your app before(or automatically) deploying. And your hosting serve static files from build/dist folder

Comment: I updated the post to include my build folder. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You need to configure that your website in build folder. Right now you serve public folder

Comment: Can you please explain how I can do that? Sorry I am new to web development and react. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't work with firebase too) But you can take a look to article https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-firebase-hosting-98063c5bf425

Comment: Looks like it could help you)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set baseUrl for your resources css/js/images/fonts

In your package.json add a field named "homepage" and set its value to your domain in your case weatherman-9860a.web.app

example code

```
....
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"homepage": "weatherman-9860a.web.app",
"eslintConfig": {
.....
```

afterwards run build script which will result in base url attached to resources

```
.....
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="/weatherman-9860a.web.app/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/weatherman-9860a.web.app/logo192.png" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/weatherman-9860a.web.app/manifest.json" />
<title>React App</title>
<link
  href="/weatherman-9860a.web.app/static/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
.....
```

one other way which may work is to set

```
<base href="weatherman-9860a.web.app">
```

in your head tag in your builded index.html which will resolve routes like

```
 /static/css/some.css ----> weatherman-9860a.web.app/static/css/some.css
```

Comment: Another quick solution would be to pass publicUrl to build script which in turn will replace %PUBLIC_URL% with the provided one 
Mac/Linux:  PUBLIC_URL=https://weatherman-9860a.web.app npm run build
Windows:   set PUBLIC_URL=https://weatherman-9860a.web.app npm run build